# S3 Storage- PDF file is not opening using distribution url after uploading using C# code

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sharepoint-online

I am using C# to upload the files in S3 storage.recently I am facing issue to open the pdf file which has _ (underscore) in file name using distribution url. In past it was working.if we remove the _ from file name or upload the same file manually it is working.

Below is the error I am getting.

[image]

I tried to putting content type in header for PutObjectRequest method,but no luck.

Please help me to solve this issue. This issue is occurring on Chrome and Edge. For Firefox it opens the document

Comment: What do you mean by "using distribution url"? Are you saying that you have an Amazon CloudFront distribution in front of the Amazon S3 bucket? If so, can the object be directly accessed from the bucket? What program are you using to access the object -- that error message doesn't seem to be a standard browser message (or at least not for Chrome)?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am using Amazon S3 bucket.When I open it from bucket, it is opening. We have make these files as public readable.and public url is not working to open the file.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the URL you are using? This will help us understand if the image is being served from S3 or from CloudFront. You are welcome to change the filename to keep it private. Please also tell us HOW you are trying to open the file -- for example, are you just putting the URL in a browser, or are you using a problem to download it?

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein - I am working with Kanchan in the same issue, here is the direct link which will allo you to test: https://www.lenze.com/en-de/go/akb/202300052/1/

Open this link and on the right side, try to download the PDF file.

Comment: How are you 'serving' that PDF file? What does `https://download.lenze.com/AKB/English/202300052/3rdParty_Commissioning%20manual%20Safety%20parameter%20handling%20i750_i950_1.pdf` link to? It doesn't seem to be coming out of an S3 bucket called `download.lenze.com`, so how is it being served to users?

Comment: Hey John! This was a funny issue - got it solved finally.

It seems that the filename was inconsistent - it contains mixes of underscores, hyphens, spaces which was making the browser failing to open the files.

The moment I renamed the file consistently, for example with only underscores OR hyphens OR only spaces - it started working!!

Thanks for your inputs as well.

Answer (score 0):

got it solved finally. It seems that the filename was inconsistent - it contains mixes of underscores, hyphens, spaces which was making the browser failing to open the files. The moment I renamed the file consistently, for example with only underscores OR hyphens OR only spaces - it started working!!